# Continue only after thread finishes

Tags: java

I created New thread in anonymous class. How can I pause the program until the thread is finish. 
for check that everything works Ok I create while loop that dont continue but I know that this is not the solution.
I look for the simplest solution.

```
 public void methodName() {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
        }
    }
    t.start()
    System.out.print("Finish");
}
```

I want that finish print only after the thread t finish.

In the thread I use an external library. And I discover that the thread finish but the function that I run inside the thread does not finish. Their is a way like Lock or Synchronize notify that I can stop the run until this function is finish?

I can put variable in the place when the run of the function is finished.

```
     ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
     query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
     public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
          if (e == null) {
           // object will be your game score
          } else {
          // something went wrong
           }
       }
       });
```

this is from the API. I want to put this Code in Thread and continue only after the done function is called. 
 Thanks,

Comment: About your edit: Are you sure about that? Threads do not finish until their run() method has finished.

Comment: @Zenadix Yes, The thread run a function that it's also a thread (this its one write in the api but the code is compiled and I can see). It seems that the thread finished but the function didnt finish to run. I have another method that called when this function finished. so I can put their an object

Comment: Maybe if you post the code I will be able to help you.

Comment: @Zenadix The code In EDIT2

Comment: Okay. If you are calling query.getInBackground(), it means that you want to do run the query _in background_. That's why it starts a new thread and returns inmediately. If you want to just wait until it's done, you should use another method (my guess is query.get()) that will run the query in the same thread, and return only when it's finished.

Comment: If it's [this ParseQuery](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html), just use the `get` method instead.

Comment: I used find() thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just call [`join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) on the thread:

```
t.start();
t.join();
System.out.print("Finish");
```

The `join` call waits for the thread to terminate before returning.

Comment: Mandatory Javadoc link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--